# How to avoid cyclic matches in fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

Here is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(Name=['Emma Howard', 'Emma Ward', 'Emma Warner', 'Emma Wayden'],
         Age=[33, 34, 43, 44], Score=[90, 95, 93, 92])
)

list2 = df['Name'].tolist()
```

I am applying fuzzywuzzy process:

```
process.extractBests(i, list2, score_cutoff=80, scorer=fuzz.ratio)
```

to extract the best matches on the column Name and it is giving the result as below:
[image]

The output I'm expecting is:
[image]

The logic is the "Emma Howard" and "Emma Ward" are already matched in the first row, hence I do not want to show "Emma Howard" in the second row matches and same for the 3rd and fourth rows.

Here is the complete **pseudo code**:

```
mat1 = []
list1 = df['Name'].tolist()
list2 = df['Name'].tolist()
list3 = df['Name'].tolist()

for i in list1:
    list2 = [x for x in list2 if x != i]
    mat1.append(process.extractBests(i, list2, score_cutoff=80, scorer=fuzz.ratio))
    list2 = list3
df['matches'] = mat1
df.to_csv("xyz.csv")
```

Comment: I don't know how many rows you have, but you _could_ consider matching across all rows simultaneously. In other words, Q Are you results stable if you change the order of your rows? Would you want them to be?

Comment: Also, do you care about the order of the matches within a row?

Comment: The number of rows is about 35k and the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, once a name has been used, it is no longer available for subsequent lines, so you can use `set` operations to remove already assigned names:

```
uniques = set(df['Name'])
matches = {}
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    uniques -= set([row.Name])  # remove current name
    res = process.extractBests(row.Name, uniques, score_cutoff=80)
    uniques -= set([name for name, score in res])  # remove best results
    matches[idx] = res
df['matches'] = pd.Series(matches)
```

**Note**: at each iteration, the comparison is faster because there are fewer rows in the set.

Output:

```
>>> df
          Name  Age  Score                                 matches
0  Emma Howard   33     90                       [(Emma Ward, 90)]
1    Emma Ward   34     95  [(Emma Wayden, 80), (Emma Warner, 80)]
2  Emma Warner   43     93                                      []
3  Emma Wayden   44     92                                      []
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I'm getting a different output than expected. This is what I'm getting                                                Name Age Score matches
Emma Howard 33 90 0
Emma Ward 34 95 1
Emma Warner 43 93 2
Emma Wayden 44 92 3

Comment: What version of Pandas do you have? I updated my answer. It should be right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using 3.7 and understood why it wasn't working earlier. In my case I do not want to remove the best matches as they could match with another name. I modified that part and got the desired result :)